# onClick, onChange, onLoad not working in my cordova project

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, onclick, onchange

I got a cordova project but when I use onClick with buttons or onChange with select, they don't work at all. Obviusly if I open a new html file and try those (same code) they works.

What could be the problem?

I read that it could be because these function doesn't work on smartphones, but that's not my case 'cause if I create a html file (with same functions) and I create the app, they normally work.

Comment: Might be due to the lack of native functions of those events. Are you using the latest version of cordova?

Comment: @k3llydev I got version 6.12.0

Comment: Try using `onTap` instead of `onClick`

Comment: @k3llydev I've already tried, but it doesn't work. I also tried creating a different html with those function but not related to Cordova.js and index.js, they work perfectly on the phone.